# Functional Testing With Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, web, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I'm struggling to find a solution( or at the very least an answer as to if it can be done) how to setup Nightwatch.js UI testing tool to show interaction between multiple users logged in on different browsers.

I am writing tests for a lobby where users can log in and chat. For this to be asserted I need more than one user. I have looked over the docs at http://nightwatchjs.org/guide and can only see ways of running tests in parallel, but not interactively. Has anyone else experienced this and come up with a shareable fix?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Their WebRTC blog posts shows a good example of two "users" interacting.

http://nightwatchjs.org/blog/testing-webrtc-apps-with-nightwatch/